# How to find new fields in the Destination table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, data-conversion

I have a table in my source data base with 100 columns on it .Where i use ssis package to load data from source data base to destination data base table.
Where table in source and destination table are same .But in some times in Destination table address fields will be changed and or new data types are added.
So how can i find new columns are changed data types in destination table while compared with the source table.

Is there any stored procedure to find missing columns or address fields and changed data types.
i can check manually but its killing my time, where i have 50 tabels where each table consists of 100 to 200 columns.

Please some one help me to find ?

Comment: sys.objects is a superset of sys.tables.  Just one part of the equation.  But you need to know column names and data types to make sure the source table has not truely changed compared to the destination!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the table names from sys.tables and all the column names from sys.columns.

You can write code to perform this operation on the destination and source databases; However, you might waste alot of time re-inventing the wheel.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Just get a trial version of SQL-Compare from the sales team at red gate.  If you like it, just buy it.  It only costs $495.

Probably a-lot less money than trying to write something yourself!

Comment: Look at Source Control from Red Gate.  It can help you with control issues over the schemas.  I can actually store data from simple x-ref tables.